# how to use counter if a certain condition is met?

Tags: python

I am working on a video analysis project. I have a situation where if a person comes in front of the object (e.g. bag)(bounding boxes intersect ) my pre-defined function should wait for 100 counts before calling it as a belonging of a person.
I have written the following code :

```
count = 0
iou_value = oneObject.intersection_over_union(image,humanRegion_bbs,belongings_bbs)
if iou_value is not None and iou_value > th_iou and count > 100 :
        oneObject.setBelongings(belongingsList) #this sets the belongings to the person
```

I want this setBelongings() to wait for 100 counts before running. This is just a part of a long code I have added. The whole code runs once each frame of a video

Comment: sorry I made a mistake while writing it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the `if` condition into 2 part. Check for iou_value in the first `if` and if the condition is false, reset the `count` to 0. If the condition is true, check whether the `count` value exceeds 100. If that is true, execute `setBelongings`

```
iou_value = oneObject.intersection_over_union(image,humanRegion_bbs,belongings_bbs)

if iou_value is not None and iou_value > th_iou:
    if count > 100 :
        oneObject.setBelongings(belongingsList) #this sets the belongings to the person
else:
    count = 0
```

Comment: can I add this while loop below if clause?

Comment: what is the purpose of adding the loop below if clause? do you also want to check for `iou_value is not None and iou_value > th_iou` condition every time? or do you want to run the loop if `iou_value is not None and iou_value > th_iou` is `true`?

Comment: I want to check for iou_value is not None and iou_value > th_iou condition every time/ every frame of a video

Comment: I want to keep on checking this condition from 0 to 100 for 1000s of frames. I am confused about how to reset the value of count

Comment: is the count being increased anywhere else?

Comment: also I don't see any point of checking for `iou_value is not None and iou_value > th_iou and count > 100` for every `count` value, since the condition always fail unless `count` value exceeds 100

Comment: yes. I am incrementing at the end of the main function. Actually, if I do it inside the loop it again starts with 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184677/discussion-between-andreas-and-prb).